# Android sqlite database sqlite database empty _id fields

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

My database creates and populates without any problems. I even have a custom adapter to display the rows in listviews in my activity. 
The problem is my _id column doesn't actually have any ids. 
I have a dialogue box come up on listItemClick with the data being put into text boxes, there are buttons at the bottom, I'm trying to get the 'delete' button to work so the user can delete that record. I'm trying to delete the record calling the _id however the ID column of my database is empty for all my records. The dialogue box displays the ID number for each item and they come up as 0 for all of them and when I open the database with sqlite database browser the id column is completely empty for every record. Can anyone please help and tell me why this is? 
This is the tutorial I used: 
http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/edit-row-in-sqlite-database-using.html

Some code:

Creating database and table:

```
     public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
     public static final String KEY_LESSON = "Lesson";
     public static final String KEY_DAY = "Day";
     public static final String KEY_START = "Start";
     public static final String KEY_END = "End";
     public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "Location";

     private SQLiteDatabase db;
     private DBHelper dbHelper;
     private final Context context;

     private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table Schedule" + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTERGER PRIMARY KEY," 
     + KEY_LESSON + " text not null, " + KEY_DAY + " text not null," + KEY_START + " text not null, " + KEY_END 

public void deleteEntry(int id) {

  db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" +id, null);

 }
```

Dialogue:

```
      myDialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

      db.open();
  db.deleteEntry(item_id);

  }
  });
```

Comment: can you make sure the query is correct? e.g. there is no closing brackket!

Comment: Sorry Im pretty certain the query syntax is correct, although the copy and pasting may be a bit less accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
" INTERGER PRIMARY KEY,"
```

This would be better:

```
" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
```

Comment: i did some research and am under the impression that if integer primary key is specified then it will automatically autoincrement? i did in fact try this but it gave me the error 'AUTOINCREMENT IS ONLY ALLOWED ON AN INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (CODE 1)'

Comment: yes, it will. You must spell *INTEGER* correctly, that's the main thing. Just to be sure you see: you have __INTERGER__ in your code.

Comment: Ahh i feel like such a fool after spending hours trying to figure out the problem! Thank you very kindly this has corrected my problem.